# Django/Ajax/Jquery running two ajax requests in the same event.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I think I'm really close to getting this working but I need some help with the Jquery as everything works as intended on the second click and beyond.  It just doesn't work on the first click.

I'm basically trying to replicate the youtube like and dislike buttons. So you click the thumbs up, it shows +1 and if you click it again it subtracts one.  All that logic works until I get into the AJAX and Jquery portion.

I have one ajax request that adds the user to the "liked" ManyToManyField. Then I have one apiview that I'm connecting to just produce the upvote and downvote count, then displaying that into the template.

This all works, but again the first click produces the correct result in the console. The second click produces the "opposite" result in the template and correct result in the console. Then of course if I reload every time I click "up" it works as intended but i'm trying to prevent reloading.

**template - Jquery/Ajax**

```
$(".upvote-btn").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault()
      var this_ = $(this)
      var upvoteToggleUrl = this_.attr("data-href")
      var voteCountAPIUrl = "{% url 'streams:vote-count' streampost.pk %}";
      $.ajax({
        url: upvoteToggleUrl,
        method: 'GET',
        data: {},
        success: function(data){

        }, error: function(error){
          console.log(error)
          console.log("error")
        }
      })
      $.ajax({
        url: voteCountAPIUrl,
        method: 'GET',
        data: {},
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data.upvotes)
          console.log(data.downvotes)
          $('.upvote-count').text(data.upvotes);
        }, error: function(error){
          console.log(error)
          console.log("error")
        }
      })
    })
```

**HTML**

```
<p>
  Upvotes
  <div class="upvote-count" data-href="{% url 'streams:vote-count' streampost.pk %}">
      {{ streampost.upvotes.count }}
  </div>

  <a class="upvote-btn" data-href='{{ streampost.get_api_upvote_url }}'
  href='{{ streampost.get_upvote_url }}'>Up</a>

  Downvotes {{ streampost.downvotes.count }}
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like you want the upvote request to complete first before you retrieve the upvote count. To do that, you need to make the second request in the callback of the first:

```
$(".upvote-btn").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  var this_ = $(this)
  var upvoteToggleUrl = this_.attr("data-href")
  var voteCountAPIUrl = "{% url 'streams:vote-count' streampost.pk %}";
  $.ajax({
    url: upvoteToggleUrl,
    method: 'GET',
    data: {},
    success: function(data){
      $.ajax({
        url: voteCountAPIUrl,
        method: 'GET',
        data: {},
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data.upvotes)
          console.log(data.downvotes)
          $('.upvote-count').text(data.upvotes);
        }, error: function(error){
          console.log(error)
          console.log("error")
        }
      })
    }, error: function(error){
      console.log(error)
      console.log("error")
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: oh wow.... how did I not think of this. Just like nesting if statements. This works perfectly thank you so much!